# What is the difference between "in" and "for" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning

Here is the full sentence;

> Students enrolled **in** a minimum of 12 credits, whether they are Language
>   Center Students or regular students, are subject to all University
>   regulations.

If I drop a course and finish the semester with 10credits does this still hold?

I personally think that if we use *in*  it covers all the semester meaning that once you drop a course the law doesn't apply anymore and if we use *for* it covers the beginning of the semester once you registered if the credits are 12 or more then the law will be applied no matter if you drop a course or not.

Comment: What is "SCH"?.

Comment: *For* isn't used in the sentence. Are you asking if you can replace the existing *in* with *for*?

Comment: SCH stands for credit and yes I am asking if I replace it with for what would change